# Does battery chemistry matter for state of charge determination (discharge only)?

Tags: battery-chemistry

Someone in a chat was discussing this and I am curious.

If I have a fuel gauge that explicitly states a certain chemistry and I use another chemistry  is that ok ? For instance, the part below, is for Li-ion/Li-Polymer and LiFePO4, but can I use it with a Primary Lithium in a **discharge** case only ?

[image]

Comment: Are the discharge curves compatible?

Comment: Safe option: with any Lithium cell use the correct charge AND discharge curve.

Comment: Define "OK". With LFP almost all the action happens between 3.3V and 3.0V - the last 1% sees a rapid drop to 2.5V. That's going to be a long way from accurate with any other type of cell.

Comment: I think it's unlikely that this kind of 'gas-gauge' IC is going to be particularly accurate on any primary cell. It uses Coulomb-Counting (amongst other things in its "Impedance Track" algorithm) to help it work out what "full" looks like - and with a primary cell there's never any charge activity. If you can program it with all the details of your particular cell then you'll probably get better results, but I don't know whether or not that's practical or possible.